# Acces root user Python Anywhere bash console

Tags: bash, sudo, su

How can I access super user in python anywhere? I've tried sudo su in the bash console but it won't let me.

I expect to be able to access the root user to configure security for users, folders and groups.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this forum: [How do I get root access in bash](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/29098/).

You **cannot** access root user at `pythonanywhere`.